# Bug with CSS -moz-perspective

Tags: css, mozilla, webkit-perspective

I have a mistake with the perspective property..
If you see [this JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/TTDH7/4/) on Google Chrome (v33) and Mozilla Firefox (v28), I have a difference between them..
I can reproduce this error on Chrome if I comment the code :

```
-webkit-perspective: 2500px;
-moz-perspective: 2500px;
perspective: 2500px;
```

How can I have the same result on the both browsers ?

Thank you all for helping and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: mate, what's your question?

Comment: How can I have the same result on the both browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set : `position:absolute` to `#header-cube-container` instead of `#header-cube`.

Comment: FF seems gets confused with absolute, height/width 100% and translate to calculate area where transform and perspective is applied . it keeps resizing screen height width, so perspective angle keeps being recalculated. Drop , width & height of #header cube and it's a little better ... but doesn't fixes it, it just shows and amplify behavior.my english is really not good enough , wish i add a proper link to give you :)